# Any function to format 5 as 5/5/5?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Suppose my cell contains 5 . I want 5/5/5 in cell B of excel sheet.Like
`A   5`
`B   5/5/5`
`A   10`
`B   10/10/10`
How to do it in excel sheet using any function?Any help?`enter code here`

Comment: you already have 27 answers for all your 17 questions. And none of them are accepted? Doesn't suit? Read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 2):

In B1 add

```
=A1 & "/" & A1 & "/" & A1
```

and drag down (from the cells bottom right corner).

Answer (score 2):

A more generalised version `=REPT(A1&"/",2)&A1`.

Comment: +1 actually answers the question for general case! I've deleted my answer with similar approach (I've used `=LEFT(REPT(A1 & "/",3),LEN(REPT(A1 & "/",3))-1)`) but your is really cool:) How I missed it?!)