# Replace a value at certain lines which starts with a particular string

Tags: regex, notepad++

Suppose I have 2 files. In both the files the string `<keyInfo name="effectiveDateNew" value="2013-06-01"/>`is present but the value date value is different.

I want to replace those dates to a constant date for all files.Like

```
<keyInfo name="effectiveDateNew" value="2013-06-01"/>
<keyInfo name="effectiveDateNew" value="2014-01-01"/>
```

will be replaced as

```
<keyInfo name="effectiveDateNew" value="2014-02-01"/>
<keyInfo name="effectiveDateNew" value="2014-02-01"/>
```

Any help using regex ?

Comment: I've aready mentioned this in your [another Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727956/any-function-to-format-5-as-5-5-5), but with no luck.. **You already have 30 answers for all your 18 questions**. And none of them are accepted! Can't believe all of them doesn't suit! Accepting answer is the way to say "Thanks" in SO. Read [**this**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Futher more, all your questions doesn't show any effort to solve them! Only requriments what should be done! I suggest you to hire a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
^(<keyInfo name="effectiveDateNew" value=")\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d("/>)$
```

with:

```
$12014-02-01$2
```

This of course assumes exact spaces etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

Find what: `(?<=<keyInfo name="effectiveDateNew" value=")\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d`
Replace with: `2014-02-01`

`(?<=)` is a positive [look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).